# Passing a jinja variable to backend

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to pass the jinja variable generated within for loop to backend when corresponding button is clicked. When i click any button the first value in the list is passed. The code I tried is

**Code**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/search_tag', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def search_tag():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("hi")
        tag_x = request.form['rawtext']
        print(tag_x)
        return render_template('index.html', messg = "SUCCESS")
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Html Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test App</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('search_tag')}}">
  <div id ="result">
    <p style="color:red">
      {% for i in ["hello","hi","travel","goal"] %}
            <li>{{ i }}
            <input type="hidden" id="rawtext" name="rawtext" value="{{ i }}">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="click" class="btn btn-info">
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </p><br>
  </div>
</form>
{{ messg }}
</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this in your html:

```
<input type="hidden" id="rawtext" name="rawtext{{loop.index}}" value="{{ i }}">
```

Also you need a for loop in your flask code to iterate over all the names.

```
@app.route('/search_tag', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def search_tag():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("hi")
        for i in ["hello","hi","travel","goal"]:
           tag_x = request.form[i]
           print(tag_x)
        return render_template('index.html', messg = "SUCCESS")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But its not numbers. It can be strings. I gave numbers as an example. Updated the html code. There was one error of form closing. Corrected it now. Now only the first value is passing even if i click any button

Comment: That is because you have the same name for all the inputs. You should mind changing the name as well in order to catch all the separate inputs. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thankyou for the response. Can you post me to show how flask side to be done. Bit confused. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved by using radio button and advice from @Ioannis Skaltsas (Thanks for you suggestion. If there is any better way please suggest like ajax or something else).. Corrected code is --->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test App</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('search_tag')}}">
  <div id ="result">
    <p style="color:red">
      {% for i in ["hello","hi","travel","goal"] %}               
            <input type="radio" id="rawtext" name="rawtext" value="{{ loop.index }}">{{ i }} <br>
        {% endfor %}
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="click" class="btn btn-info">
    </p><br>
  </div>
</form>
{{ messg }}
</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

Since originally list was generated in the python code(here statically used in html code), based on the selected loop index submitted using button, I could take the value from list at the python end.