# How to pass jinja2 loop variable to app route function with flask?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I have an html page that displays documents and their preview sorted by their pagerank value. I want to make it so that when the user clicks a document, it takes them to the corresponding document

html:

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 text-white">
  <h1 class="display-1">Boolean Model</h1>
  {% for doc, pr in q_res_bool.items() %}  // e.g. "doc1.txt: 0.6459865341"
    <a href="/document">
      <div class="m-3">
        <h2 class="mt-5">{{ doc }} <span class="h6 text-dark-emphasis">({{ pr[:5] }})</span></h2>
        <p class="col-7">{{ boolPreview[doc] }}</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

This is the general idea that i want (document route in app.py):

```py
# Document page
@app.route('/document')
def view_document(doc):
    with open(f"docs/{doc}") as f:
        document = f.read()
    return render_template("result.html", document=document)
```

How do i pass the variable in the loop to this function as parameter?
I thought of putting something along the lines of

```html
<input type="hidden" id="{{ doc }}" name="{{ doc }}" value="{{ doc }}">
```

in my html, going by [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70276207/passing-a-jinja-variable-to-backend) and getting the value with `request.args.get()` but i end up with the same problem of not knowing what to pass as parameter

example screenshot of html:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing my link tag to `<a href="/docs/{{ doc }}">`

and then accessing it via a [variable rule](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) in my app.py:

```py
@app.route('/docs/<doc>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def view_document(doc):
    print("route received")
    with open(f"docs/{doc}") as f:
        document = f.read()
    return render_template("result.html", document = document, title = doc)
```